# Задача из codewars на digital root. Выдаёт правильный результат, но не засчитывает решение

Tags: javascript, if

Есть задача на codewars:
Digital root is the recursive sum of all the digits in a number.
Given n, take the sum of the digits of n. If that value has more than one digit, continue reducing in this way until a single-digit number is produced. The input will be a non-negative integer.

Я решил её таким кодом:

```
function digitalRoot(n) {
  n = n.toString().split('').map((num) => Number(num));
  
  n = n.reduce((previous, current) => previous + current, 0);
  /* console.log(n); */
  if (n < 10) {
    return n;
  } else if (n >= 10) {
    digitalRoot(n);
  }
}

digitalRoot(16);
console.log('------');
digitalRoot(942);
console.log('------');
digitalRoot(132189);
console.log('------');
digitalRoot(493193);
```

Ответы на примеры верные, но задача не засчитывается. Пишет `expected undefined to equal 6`.
Я заменил if else на ? и всё заработало:

```
return n > 10 ? digitalRoot(n) : n;
```

Можете пожалуйста объяснить, где ошибка в if else?

Comment: А return кто напишет?

Comment: Я думал, что при новом вызове функции, выполнение снова дойдёт до if else и если верно первое условие, будет возвращено n

Comment: всё так.... только оно возвращает его "куда-то". И это "куда-то"  - то место, откуда была вызвана функция, а она была вызвана из другой такой же, а не извне.....вот и полетит она туда обратно внутрь.... а внутри не будет поймана и возвращена во внешний мир

Answer (score 0):

Ответ ожидал получить число. Однако при `else if (n >= 10) {`   финальный стек никуда ничего не вернёт (точнее вернёт `undefined`)... нужен `return digitalRoot(n);` . В тернарнике это вполне себе происходит.

Comment: Вот оно что, благодарю за ответ.